# 3 coin flips first is head or at least one is head and what is probability

Tags: probability

What is the difference between case where first coin is head why those event have 1/4 and when we don't know pleace of coin probability is 1/7 when order doesn't matters? In each case we head the same set of heads and we can start with two heads not only one

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: why probability of getting 3 heads in case when we know that first coin flips head is bigger than when we know that et least one of flips is head in both cases we can make 2 sets one with head flip and other with two unknown flips

Comment: For three flips there are only eight possibilities.  List them all, mark the ones that satisfy each requirement, and note the results.